# SQL: count the number of values two distinct entries have

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following SQLite table:

```
Name  | Lived_in
----------------
John  | Canada
John  | UK
James | Canada
James | UK
Mary  | UK
Mike  | USA
```

Is there any way of listing the pairs formed by the distinct values in col_1 (Names), alongside the number of values they share in col_2 (Lived_in), and sorted by the later?

In my example, this would yield:

```
 Node A |  Node B | Shared values
-------------------------------
 John   |  James  |  2
 John   |  Mary   |  1
 James  |  Mary   |  1
```

Note: if that can't be done, I'll accept an answer that returns all pairs that have X relationships in common, where I have to specify what X is for each request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also recommend doing an inner join, but I would specify that the `name` values cannot be equal

```
select t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2, count(*)
from table t1 inner join
     table t2
     on t1.Lived_in = t2.Lived_in
     and t1.name > t2.name
group by t1.name,t2.name
```

note that use of `>` instead of `<>` in the inequality operator is used to avoid duplicates (John-James and James-John)

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/26a76/9

Comment: just missing 'order by count(*) desc' at the end!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a self-join and `group by`:

```
select t1.name, t2.name, count(*)
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.Lived_in = t2.Lived_in
group by t1.name, t2.name;
```

Comment: @bsuire . . . That's funny.  I had a typo in the `group by`, but you seem to have gotten your solution.